# In Excel, need to count cells that are colored from conditional formatting, then create report of specific results

Tags: excel, vba

I have a spreadsheet with names (in column A), and each name has 10 numbers in a row (Columns B-K). I am using Conditional Formatting to highlight cells in green that contain numbers which match other criteria.

Now, I need to count the green highlighted cells for each name, and create a report of the results. For example, I need a report, or list, or graph that shows all the names of the people that have 8 of the 10 cells highlighted in green. (Names with 8 green cells = Joe, Mike, Sue)

I am using the following formula just to count each row of green colored cells, but the list will have too many names to repeat this formula for each row. So I have not created a report based on the results of this formula, because I need a better formula to do the initial green cell count. Then, I need help on the best way to create the final report. Thank you!

[image]

```
Public Sub CountColorCells()
    'Variable declaration
    Dim rng As Range
    Dim lColorCounter As Long
    Dim rngCell As Range
    'Set the range
    Set rng = Sheet1.Range("B2:K2")
    'loop throught each cell in the range
    For Each rngCell In rng
        'Checking Green color
        If Cells(rngCell.Row, rngCell.Column).DisplayFormat.Interior.Color = _
                                                       RGB(169, 208, 142) Then
            lColorCounter = lColorCounter + 1
        End If
    Next
    'Display the value in cell L2
    Sheet1.Range("L2") = lColorCounter
 End Sub
```

Comment: Base the count on the logic you use to conditionally format the cells green.

Comment: Thank you Mike. I will try this. If you can elaborate, that would be great. Thank you!

Comment: So use countifs() with the criteria you use for the conditional formatting - you have not given those ...

Comment: I am using =COUNTIF($O:$T,B2)>0 to pull the criteria from columns O through T. (If columns B:K match the numbers placed in columns O:T, then B:K cells highlight in green

Answer (score 0):

I believe you really need a UDF here (user defined function). With a UDF, you can enter a formula in that would look like this

in cell L2: `=CountColorCells(B2:K2)` and that UDF would return the number of highlighted cells in the range.

So there are some changes to make to your code.

First, you want to declare it as a `Function`, not a `Sub` since we need to return a value.

Next, your code is close to being correct as it is. The only problem is that when you're iterating over the range (which will be changed to an input parameter of the function), you don't need to break out the `Row` and `Column`. That's already baked in to the `rngCell`. So your UDF now looks like this (and works very fast)

```
Public Function CountColorCells(ByRef thisRange As Range) As Long
    Dim lColorCounter As Long
    Dim rngCell As Range
    For Each rngCell In thisRange
        If rngCell.Interior.Color = RGB(169, 208, 142) Then
            lColorCounter = lColorCounter + 1
        End If
    Next
    CountColorCells = lColorCounter
End Function
```

And now (only because I can't help it ;) ), here is a version of the UDF that I would use. There are now some optional parameters for Red, Green, and Blue color values you can add, just in case you want to count a different color. So with this UDF version, you can count cells that are RED by using the formula `=CountColorCells(B2:K2,255,0,0)`. This is just an extended example of what you can do:

```
Public Function CountColorCells(ByRef thisRange As Range, _
                                Optional ByVal r As Long = 169, _
                                Optional ByVal g As Long = 208, _
                                Optional ByVal b As Long = 142) As Long
    Dim checkColor As Long
    checkColor = RGB(r, g, b)

    Dim lColorCounter As Long
    Dim rngCell As Range
    For Each rngCell In thisRange
        If rngCell.Interior.Color = checkColor Then
            lColorCounter = lColorCounter + 1
        End If
    Next
    CountColorCells = lColorCounter
End Function
```

Comment: I believe you need `rngCell.DISPLAYFORMAT.Interior.Color` to count cells colored by conditional formatting.

Comment: You might also use `Optional ByVal r As Long = 169, Optional ByVal g As Long = 208, Optional ByVal b As Long = 142)` If r, g and/or b are not supplied then they get the default values.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. When I try to assign the macro, I do not get an option for CountColorCells. Should I be assigning the macro in VB the same way that I did the previous code? I found that info at this site > https://excelsirji.com/vba-code-count-color-cells-conditional-formatting/ . It worked, but only for each row. Thank you for your advice!

Comment: The function above should be placed in a VBA module, not as part of the Worksheet object (in the VBA Editor, from the menu Insert-->Module). The reason the code in your original post (and the link) only works for a single row is because the row is defined inside the function. Setting the range as a parameter gives you the flexibility to define any size range and count the colors. I also used @user10981853 excellent suggestion to edit my function above to set defaults for the parameters.

Comment: Hmmm when I create the module again in VBA, it still doesn't give me the option to choose CountColorCells. I only get that option with the original code to count each row. I am trying to compare the codes to see how I can get that option to appear in the module.

Comment: I have been trying to get this function to work in VBA in every way that i can think of, and it doesn't work. If there is any way that I can get the function to give me the macro option to choose CountColorCells, please let me know.

Comment: If any has any ideas, I would truly appreciate any help I can get. thank you.

Comment: So when you click on a cell and start to type `=Cou`, it doesn't come up with a list of formulas that includes `CountColorCells`?